# SSDT schema comparison error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: identifierGroup

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

With SSDT in VS 2017 I cannot do a schema comparison of two databases.  Steps to reproduce:

1. Tools >> SQL Server >> New Schema Comparison
2. Select a source (a SQL 2017 database)
3. Select a target (a SQL 2017 database)
4. Compare
5. Get error:  Value cannot be null.
   Parameter name: identifierGroup

I've also tried in VS 2015 which was still installed and it failed there too.

Comment: It works for me... you need to provide more detail, try to identify which object is causing the error.

Comment: Interesting, I was trying this against two databases across the network and it failed on those (even though I verified I can connect and I'm sysadmin on that instance).  I tried this against two local databases and it worked though.  ??

Comment: Interestingly, it works with one of the sides of the comparison connecting to the instance on the network and it doesn't matter if it's the target or source or which of the two databases on the network.  As long as it's one db on the network and one local db then it works fine.  If it's two databases on the same instance over the network is when it fails with that error.

Answer (score 1):

This error starts after the identity Cache is disabled

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET IDENTITY_CACHE = OFF
```

After re-enabling it, the error disappears:

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET IDENTITY_CACHE = ON
```

Don't forget to restart sql service.

Comment: Still no luck. Comments on the OP question suggest a network issue, so I have tried with two local instances with identity cache on... No luck. Tried VS2017 (I am on VS2019). I am running two SQL instances (2017 & 2019). To clarify, I have placed both databases on the same version (SQL2019) which is what they are native to. Online searches show that what you have suggested IS one possible solution, but it doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and not yet found a solution, I suppose there are some relation with orphan users.

I did a workaround that worked fine to me.

1. Create a new empty database
2. Compare the origin database with this new one.
3. Update the new database with de resulting script.
4. Make this new database the new origin and compare with the destination database.
5. Update de destination database.

Maybe this can helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found a different answer which worked for me several times so far using SSDT / Visual Studio 2019 against SQL server 2019 databases.

https://hendrikbulens.com/2018/10/03/how-to-fix-sql-server-data-tools-error-unexpected-exception-caught-during-population-of-source-model-in-visual-studio-2017/

Hope this helps someone.  Ideally Microsoft needs to patch this issue, which looks like a longstanding bug at this point.  I looked for such a patch but did not find one.  If anyone finds one, please do link it here.